# regex for checking if a string matches a package or the other

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if a string looks like `my.company.foo.A` or `your.whatever.bar.B`.

The point is, I want to match or strings that have `.bar.` or `.foo.`
And I have this regex
`(.*\\.foo\\..* | .*\\.bar\\..*)`

but which didn't seem to work.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: (my\\.company\\..+) or (my\\.company\\.(.*foo|bar.*))

Comment: No, even without the `my.`, it should still match `a.foo.C`, but it doesn't

Comment: take out the space of your regex `(.*\\.foo\\..*|.*\\.bar\\..*)`

Comment: @JorgeCompos: You're a life saver!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space on your regex:

```
(.*\\.foo\\..* | .*\\.bar\\..*)
              | |
```

Take it out and you should be fine

```
(.*\\.foo\\..*|.*\\.bar\\..*)
```